# Wald lemma and Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Consider the following version of Wald lemma for Brownian motion.

How can we prove the last inequality: $$E[X_k|\mathcal{F}_{k-1}] \leq M(4^{k-1})+E[\max_{0 \leq r \leq 4^k-4^{k-1}}B_r]-2^{k+1}?$$

[image]

Comment: does'nt $\max_{0 \leq r \leq 4^k-4^{k-1}}B_r$ has the same law  as $\max_{4^{k-1} \leq r \leq 4^k}B_r$ ?

Comment: Is $\max_{4^{k-1}\leq r \leq 4^k}B_r$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_{k-1}$ ? Why?

Comment: Well this comes readily from the definition of a Brownian motion (increments $B_t-B_s$ for $t>s$ are independent of $\mathcal {F}_s$.

Comment: It wouldn't be $\max_{4^{k-1} \leq r \leq 4^k}B_r-B_{4^{k-1}}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{k-1}$ ? How can we remove $B_{4^{k-1}}$ ?

Comment: We don't care about that because the laws of $B_r-B_{4^{k-1}}$ and $B_r-B_0=B_r$ are the same over the intervals of interest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,   observe that for every $t \in [0,4^k]$, we have

$$B(t) \le M(4^{k-1})+[\max_{0 \leq s \leq 4^k-4^{k-1}} B_{4^{k-1}+s}-B_{4^{k-1}} ]   \,.$$
(Consider  separately the cases $t \le 4^{k-1}$ and $t \in [4^{k-1},4^k]$.)
In other words,
$$M(4^k) \le M(4^{k-1})+ [\max_{0 \leq s \leq 4^k-4^{k-1}} B_{4^{k-1}+s}-B_{4^{k-1}} ]  \quad (*) \,.$$

Recall that the Markov property ensures that the process $ \{B_{4^{k-1}+s}-B_{4^{k-1}}\}_{s \ge 0}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}^+(4^{k-1})$, and
has the same law as  $ \{B_s\}_{s \ge 0}$.
Thus, if $\mathcal{F}_{k-1}$ is (less than  ideal) shorthand for $\mathcal{F}^+(4^{k-1})$, taking conditional expectation in $(*)$ yields that

$$E[M(4^k)|\mathcal{F}_{k-1}] \leq M(4^{k-1})+E[\max_{0 \leq r \leq 4^k-4^{k-1}}B_r] \,.$$

Comment: Hi! I also noticed, in your book, that you used the reflection principle to prove the result. I think an alternative way would be to use Doob inequality: $E[\sup_{r \in [0,1]}B_r] \leq (E[(\sup_{r \in [0,1]}B_r)^2])^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq 2(E[B_1^2])^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq 2.$ Right?

Comment: Absolutely! The reflection principle gives a slightly sharper bound, but Doob's inequality is more general.